# How do i generate a list of integers from 1 to 200 where it only prints the first 20 odd/even numbers?

Tags: python-3.x, list

How do i generate a list of integers from 1 to 200 where it only prints the first 20 odd/even numbers?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean by "first 20 odd/even numbers"? Please give example output, and like norok2 said, the code you've already tried.

Comment: @Jörg That's a bit intense for a newbie to do, don't you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This Code :

```
odd=[i for i in range(1,201,2)]
even=[i for i in range(2,201,2)]
print("Odd : ",odd[0:20]) # First 20 Odd numbers between 1 to 200
print("Even : ",even[0:20]) # First 20 Even numbers between 1 to 200
```